# Is it possible to only find real roots with mullers method?

Tags: roots, real-numbers

I am trying to implement a bubble temperature calculation for a mixture of chemicals and i need to find the temperature where  the sum of the K values multiplied with the concentration of the liquid phase x -1 equals zero. In the literature mullers method is recommended but my problem is that for some points i get complex values but I only want to find real roots (because im looking for the temperature)
In another book (numerical methods for engineers) it was recommended to discard of the temperature which is the farest away from the new estimate to avoid complex roots, but with this approach i am also getting sometimes complex numbers.
do you guys have any idea on how to solve my problem and to avoid complex numbers?
thank you very much in advance
greetings
Lukas

Comment: What kind of model are you using ? Ideal K-values or something else ?

Comment: an equation of state model (PSRK), the K values are assumed to be constant and updated with the fugacities: ln Knew=ln Kold-damping*ln(fugacity_vapor/fugacity_liq)

Comment: I suppose that you solve the problem in a single loop. How do you generate the starting guess ? I am curious because cubic EoS are my domain (I spent almost 40 years with them).

Comment: what do you mean with single loop?  regarding the starting guesses i use Aspen so if the bubble temperature in aspen is for example at 234 K (at a given composition) , i use 230 K 240 K and 275 K, but i also noticed that even a small change in the starting value scan lead to a complex solution

Comment: and for the damping factor i used a value of 0.15, but honestly i am quite unsure about the starting values and the damping factor

Comment: Can you just write down the exact equation you are trying to solve? That may be quite helpful. I usually recommend running the trivial bisection simultaneously with anything like Newton or Muller: it will be finally outpaced by them at the endgame but it will provide the necessary sanity check in the beginning, so if you get something strange for the Muller iteration (a root outside the bisection interval or a complex number), you just reset it to the middle of the bisection interval and continue from there. Numerically it is cheap and slows you down only twice.